# how to convert to NotNull by using enum in Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

How can I convert the following code to accepted `NotNull` inside `enum` class by using `Kotlin`?

Note: i'm using this enum between two activity and one activity has 2 adapters.

**Here is enum class**

```
enum class Adapterx {
ADAPTER_1,
ADAPTER_2;


    companion object {
        fun fromOrdinal(ordinal: Int): Adapterx? {
            return Adapterx.values().firstOrNull { it.ordinal == ordinal }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot restrict the `ordinal: Int` parameter as you've define it, you have two choices if you receive an ordinal which is not part of the enum, or is out of bounds:

- Return a default value
- Throw an exception

IMHO both cases are plausible if you document properly the method.

Here's a case where you return just a default value if you ask for an ordinal that does not exist:

```
class KotlinEnumTest {
  enum class Adapterx {
    ADAPTER_1,
    ADAPTER_2;

    companion object {
      val defaultValue = ADAPTER_1
      fun fromOrdinal(ordinal: Int): Adapterx =
          Adapterx.values().getOrElse(ordinal, { _ -> defaultValue })
    }
  }

  @Test fun testEnumOrdinals() {
    val resultAdapter1 = Adapterx.fromOrdinal(0)
    Assert.assertEquals(Adapterx.ADAPTER_1, resultAdapter1)

    val resultAdapter2 = Adapterx.fromOrdinal(1)
    Assert.assertEquals(Adapterx.ADAPTER_2, resultAdapter2)

    // The following returns the default value ADAPTER_1
    val resultOrdinalIndexOutOfBounds = Adapterx.fromOrdinal(2)
    Assert.assertEquals(Adapterx.ADAPTER_1, resultOrdinalIndexOutOfBounds)
  }
}
```